# How do I cascade a @bind-Value?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

In my razor page I have:

```
<Rating @bind-Value="@Model.RoiRating" Descriptions="@Rating.RoiDescriptions"/>
```

In my Rating.razor component I have:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column align-center">
    <MudRating @bind-SelectedValue="@Value" HoveredValueChanged="OnHoveredValueChanged" />
    <MudText Typo="Typo.subtitle2" Class="deep-purple-text mt-2">@RatingText</MudText>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int Value { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<int> ValueChanged { get; set; }
}
```

Based on breakpoints, when I click on a star in the MudRating control, the `Rating.Value` setter is called setting it to the clicked value.

However, the `Model.RoiRating` setter is never called. What do I have to do to cascade the binding?

---

**Update:** Here's what I changed it to based on the below. And it works. But as I asked in a comment below - I don't understand how this is different.

Changes are only in my Rating.razor

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column align-center">
    <MudRating SelectedValue="Value" SelectedValueChanged="OnSelectedValueChanged" HoveredValueChanged="OnHoveredValueChanged" />
    <MudText Typo="Typo.subtitle2" Class="deep-purple-text mt-2">@RatingText</MudText>
</div>
```

And my Rating.razor.cs

```
[Parameter]
public int Value { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public EventCallback<int> ValueChanged { get; set; }

private async Task OnSelectedValueChanged(int rating)
{
    // pre @HH I've commented this out. But doing so causes the Value to revert back to 0.
    // Value = rating;
    await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(rating);
}
```

So the MyPage.razor file still does an @bind-Value on Rating.razor and that works great. But Rating.razor explicitly does Value= and ValueChanged=

And a final question. Is the requirement for `InvokeAsync()` because even if the called method just sets a property in an object, that change will cause a render update and that render update needs to be in the UI context/thread?

Comment: Short version: I recommend not putting too much effort into 2-way binding, unless you really need to be able to interactively set the value.

Comment: Also see my other answer to `InvokeAsync`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For automatic two way binding, your Rating component should have a property which by convention is called `ValueChanged`

```cs
[Parameter] public EventCallback<int> ValueChanged { get; set; }
```

However, you should not bind directly to a public parameter - instead use the `bind:get/:set` as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#bind-across-more-than-two-components).

```html
<div class="d-flex flex-column align-center">
    <MudRating @bind-SelectedValue:get="@Value" @bind-SelectedValue:set="@ValueChanged"  HoveredValueChanged="OnHoveredValueChanged" />
    <MudText Typo="Typo.subtitle2" Class="deep-purple-text mt-2">@RatingText</MudText>
</div>
```

```cs
@code {
  [Parameter]
  public int Value { get; set; }
  [Parameter] 
  public EventCallback<int> ValueChanged { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Should be noted the `bind:get/:set` attribute is only available for .Net 7+

Comment: Sorry, I do have a ValueChanged event. Forgot to put it in the code. Why do I need to do the get/set? Should bind carry through the 2 steps?

Comment: Because of the reasons in the documentation - data should flow one way down and one way up - if you bind like you have, you can get conflicts with the parameter state held by Blazor

Comment: @DavidThielen - To answer your question above, `@bind-SelectedValue="@Value"` is a Razor directive.  You're telling the Razor compiler to set up two way binding to the `Value` property which is what it does.  A non-no as stated by @HH.  There's no magical linkage built to `ValueChanged`.  If that's what you want then you need to use the `bind-value:get/set' defined above.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I think I understand that bind-Value is identical to Value and in ValueChanged, setting the property to the passed value. What I don't understand is while you can do this for 1 level (parent => component) it fails for 2 levels (parent => component => sub-component).  
My question is why it doesn't carry through for 2 levels. I have done as suggested and it works which is great. But I don't like not understanding this well enough to know why it has to be set explicitly.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis & MisterMagoo - you've provided a solution and I appreciate that. Thank you. I'm asking follow up questions because I want to understand why. The old "Teach a man to fish..."

Comment: See added answer.

Comment: How is `@bind-SelectedValue:get="@Value" @bind-SelectedValue:set="@ValueChanged"` different from `SelectedValue="@Value" SelectedValueChanged="@ValueChanged"`? Also, the link you provided does not provide, IMO, a clear explanation (not your fault!) because it doesn't pas up a value to set in the parent, it just at each level passes its own string. So I think I understand, but not sure.

Comment: I'm not going to attempt to answer how they differ because I haven't studied them in that way, but they are both valid and logically perform the same job.

Answer (score 2):

The answer posted by @MisterMagoo is a good and compact solution.

But as an explanation and for dotnet versions < 7 :

The binding `@bind-SelectedValue="Value"` does a complete 2-way binding but it does not 'notify' anything else. And you should not bind to a [Parameter] property.  So break it up in 2 parts:

```html
    <MudRating SelectedValue="Value" SelectedValueChanged="UpdateValue" ... />
```

and add

```cs
async Task UpdateValue(int newValue)
{
// Value = newValue; -- do NOT do this
   await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(newValue); // this was missing
}
```

Note that the parent component will now rerender the Rating component with a new Value. That is the normal data-flow in binding.

Comment: Put aside the inner MudRating component for the moment and assume we have just the MyPage.razor and Rating.razor. bind-Value works for that. Don't I have to declare Value a [Parameter] so the MyPage can set Value= or bind-Value=? And why is it bad to bind to a [Parameter]? TIA

Comment: See the Warning block [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#component-parameters) that points [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/overwriting-parameters?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: MyPage is the consumer of a binding. Only requirement is a variable, whatever kind. But Rating is both provider and consumer, and both  answers here are about how to chain that.

Comment: Thank you - that explains it. @bind doesn't do squat for being the provider.

Comment: Sorry, one more question. Why can I not **also** assign `Value = newValue;`? Is it because MyPage has an @bind to it? And if so, how do I update `Value`? If I don't also assign to Value, it reverts back to the original value.

Comment: More or less, more directly because it's a [Parameter]. I posted 2 links in the 2nd comments here. And this works, Value does not revert. See the last sentence of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For a further explanation as to why the bind isn't passed through you need to look at (and understand) the code generated by the Razor compiler.

This:

```cs
<div class="bg-light border border-1 m-2 p-2">
    <InputNumber class="form-control" @bind-Value="this.Value" />
</div>
```

Will generate this:

```cs
        builder.OpenElement(0, "div");
        builder.AddAttribute(1, "class", "bg-light border border-1 m-2 p-2");
        builder.OpenComponent<InputNumber<int>>(100);
        builder.AddAttribute(101, "class", "form-control");
        builder.AddAttribute(102, "Value", this.Value);
        // Assigned directly to Value
        builder.AddAttribute(103, "ValueChanged", EventCallback.Factory.Create(this, RuntimeHelpers.CreateInferredEventCallback(this, __value => this.Value = __value, this.Value)));
        builder.AddAttribute(104, "ValueExpression", (Expression<Func<int>>)(() => this.Value));
        builder.CloseComponent();
        builder.CloseElement();
```

While this:

```cs
<div class="bg-light border border-1 m-2 p-2">
    <InputNumber class="form-control" @bind-Value:get="this.Value" @bind-Value:set="this.ValueChanged" />
</div>
```

```cs
        builder.OpenElement(0, "div");
        builder.AddAttribute(1, "class", "bg-light border border-1 m-2 p-2");
        builder.OpenComponent<InputNumber<int>>(100);
        builder.AddAttribute(101, "class", "form-control");
        builder.AddAttribute(102, "Value", this.Value);
        // ValueChanged is set to the event handler
        builder.AddAttribute(103, "ValueChanged", EventCallback.Factory.Create(this, RuntimeHelpers.CreateInferredEventCallback(this, this.ValueChanged, this.Value)));
        builder.AddAttribute(104, "ValueExpression", (Expression<Func<int>>)(() => this.Value));
        builder.CloseComponent();
        builder.CloseElement();
```

Here's the full demo page:

```cs
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.CompilerServices;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering;

<div class="bg-light border border-1 m-2 p-2">
    <InputNumber class="form-control" @bind-Value="this.Value" />
</div>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>Value : @this.Value</pre>
</div>

@ComponentContent

<div class="bg-light border border-1 m-2 p-2">
    <InputNumber class="form-control" @bind-Value:get="this.Value" @bind-Value:set="this.ValueChanged" />
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public int Value { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<int> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    // This is the code generated from the straight bind
    private RenderFragment ComponentContent => (builder) =>
    {
        builder.OpenElement(0, "div");
        builder.AddAttribute(1, "class", "bg-light border border-1 m-2 p-2");
        builder.OpenComponent<InputNumber<int>>(100);
        builder.AddAttribute(101, "class", "form-control");
        builder.AddAttribute(102, "Value", this.Value);
        // The provided is assigned directly to Value
        builder.AddAttribute(103, "ValueChanged", EventCallback.Factory.Create(this, RuntimeHelpers.CreateInferredEventCallback(this, __value => this.Value = __value, this.Value)));
        builder.AddAttribute(104, "ValueExpression", (Expression<Func<int>>)(() => this.Value));
        builder.CloseComponent();
        builder.CloseElement();
    };

    //This is the code generated from the `@bind-Value:get/set`
    private RenderFragment Component2Content => (builder) =>
    {
        builder.OpenElement(0, "div");
        builder.AddAttribute(1, "class", "bg-light border border-1 m-2 p-2");
        builder.OpenComponent<InputNumber<int>>(100);
        builder.AddAttribute(101, "class", "form-control");
        builder.AddAttribute(102, "Value", this.Value);
        // ValueChanged is set to the event handler
        builder.AddAttribute(103, "ValueChanged", EventCallback.Factory.Create(this, RuntimeHelpers.CreateInferredEventCallback(this, this.ValueChanged, this.Value)));
        builder.AddAttribute(104, "ValueExpression", (Expression<Func<int>>)(() => this.Value));
        builder.CloseComponent();
        builder.CloseElement();
    };

}
```

To view generated Razor code add Emit to the project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
      <EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>true</EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Files are emitted to:

*./obj/Debug/net6.0/generated*

Comment: Ok, so please correct me if I'm wrong but this means bind-Value will set the value in Rating.razor but will not cause any set or call of ValueChanged to the parent MyPage.razor. Whereas bind-Value:set will cause the ValueChanged method to be called passing Value. And that will then propagate up to the parent. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes.   In the first, the Razor compiler only knows about `Value` being associated with the component -  that's all you've told it about. It isn't a mind reader on your intent.  With `set` you are being explicit with that intention.

Answer (score 0):

And your other added question on `InvokeAsync`:

In this:

```cs
private async Task OnSelectedValueChanged(int rating)
{
    // This is a NONO.  See @HH's answer and comments
    Value = rating;
    await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(rating);
}
```

`OnSelectedValueChanged` is a UI event, so has the built in calls to `StateHasChanged`.  You `await` the UI event handler generated by the razor compiler [if it returns a Task or is sync code] so this component will get a final render after all the code triggered by the event callback in the parent completes.  In certain coding contexts that's important.

Comment: I missed that.  I've added a NONO  comment ;-)

Comment: @HH & MrCakaShaunCurtis - I follow what you're saying and the reasoning behind it. But if I don't set `Value` then following a call of `OnSelectedValueChanged(3)` I get a subsequent call of `OnSelectedValueChanged(0)` setting it back to `Value`. Setting breakpoints I'm also seeing something (call stack doesn't say what) calling the `Value` setter, with a value of 0. What else do I need to do? TIA

Comment: I may be having this reset to 0 due to a MudBlazor issue. I posted that at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76895369/mudrating-selectedvaluechanged-called-twice-on-a-click-second-time-with-the-o

Comment: I've just tested this and `MudRating` calls `OnSelectedValueChanged` twice, once with the correct value and a second time with 0

Comment: Not a particularly useful comment, but it's SO easy to make your own components in Blazor-- I very strongly recommend avoiding 3rd-party components.  Instead of researching and bug-testing someone else's code, asking questions in multiple forums, and MAYBE eventually finding an after after a day or two-- you could probably just make a component that does the same thing in a day (with a bit of practice).  In this case, I really feel there's no free lunch.  With `flex`, css isn't the finicky monster that used to make 3rd-party solutions so crucial.

Comment: See my answer to your other question on the Mudblazor issue and the reason why it happens [The flashy Hover event causing a render when Value is 0].