# MudRating.SelectedValueChanged() called twice on a click, second time with the original Value

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I have the following three tier setup.

The main razor file has:

```
<Rating @bind-Value="@Model.RoiRating" Descriptions="@Rating.RoiDescriptions"/>
```

Rating.razor is:

```
<MudRating SelectedValue="Value" SelectedValueChanged="OnSelectedValueChanged" HoveredValueChanged="OnHoveredValueChanged" />
<MudText Typo="Typo.subtitle2" Class="deep-purple-text mt-2">@RatingText</MudText>
```

And Rating.razor.cs is:

```
public partial class Rating
{
    public static string[] RoiDescriptions = new[]
    {
        "Rate the ROI",
        "Damaging",
        "Negative",
        "Ineffective",
        "Helpful",
        "Awesome!"
    };

    [Parameter]
    public string[] Descriptions { get; set; } = RoiDescriptions;

    [Parameter]
    public int Value { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<int> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    private int? _activeValue;

    private void OnHoveredValueChanged(int? val) => _activeValue = val;

    private string RatingText
    {
        get
        {
            if (_activeValue is null or < 1 or > 5)
                return Descriptions[0];
            return Descriptions[_activeValue.Value];
        }
    }
}
```

The third (innermost) tier is the MudRating control.

When I click on star #3, in the debugger I see the following calls:

```
OnSelectedValueChanged(3)
OnSelectedValueChanged(0)
```

Where/why is that second call occurring? Is it re-reading `Value` and setting back to that? I can't change `Value` [per this guidance from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/overwriting-parameters?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

So what's going on and how do I address this? Note: This question is an offshoot of [How do I cascade a @bind-Value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76891440/how-do-i-cascade-a-bind-value?noredirect=1#comment135557593_76891440)

Comment: Can't be sure without being able to debug, but probably because you are allowing the component hosting `MudRating` to re-render - because of the `await`. If you had `SelectedValueChanged=ValueChanged` the target of the EventCallback would be the parent and I suspect you would get just one render/call.

Comment: @MisterMagoo Ok you're a genius. That was it. If you would please, write as an answer and explain why. I don't understand why a re-render would revert the value. TIA

Comment: No Repro. This code works correctly on my PC. Please set up a proper [mre]. We are now missing at least OnHoveredValueChanged and the binding in MyPage.

Comment: @HH I should have done this initially - I just put up the full code behind.

Comment: It's still not complete. How do you bind in the page?  Note the "No repro".  And this is not very minimal, don't be afraid to create a temp page or even project.

Comment: @HH I've put everything in - minimized. If there's anything missing please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MisterMagoo is correct in his assertion on the re-render.

This solution also works.  It turns off the built in rendering caused by `ComponentBase`.  All the extraneous rendering goes away and the component re-renders when the parent renders and `Value` has changed.

```cs
@implements IHandleEvent

<div class="d-flex flex-column align-center">
    <MudRating @bind-SelectedValue:get="this.Value" @bind-SelectedValue:set="this.OnSelectedValueChanged" HoveredValueChanged="HandleHoveredValueChanged" />
    <MudText Typo="Typo.subtitle2" Class="deep-purple-text mt-2">@LabelText</MudText>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public int Value { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public EventCallback<int> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    private int? activeVal;

    private void HandleHoveredValueChanged(int? val) => activeVal = val;

    private async Task OnSelectedValueChanged(int rating)
    {
        await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(rating);
    }

    private string LabelText => (activeVal ?? this.Value) switch
    {
        1 => "Very bad",
        2 => "Bad",
        3 => "Sufficient",
        4 => "Good",
        5 => "Awesome!",
        _ => "Rate our product!"
    };

    //  override the ComponentBase handler so 
    //  no automated StateHasChanged calls are made
    Task IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync(EventCallbackWorkItem callback, object? arg)
    {
        return callback.InvokeAsync(arg);
    }
}
```

To demonstrate this is not normal behaviour here's a simpler Non-MudBlazor version of the control using a range input with some debug code to output the events to Output:

```
@using System.Diagnostics;

<div class="d-flex flex-column align-center">
    <label for="customRange2" class="form-label">Rate Us</label>
    <input @bind:event="oninput" @bind:get="this.Value" @bind:set="this.OnSelectedValueChanged" type="range" class="form-range" min="1" max="5">
    <div>@LabelText</div>
    @{
        Debug.WriteLine($"Rating - Rendered Value={this.Value}");
    }
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public int Value { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public EventCallback<int> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    public override Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Rating - SetParameters Called");
        return base.SetParametersAsync(parameters);
    }

    private async Task OnSelectedValueChanged(int rating)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Rating - OnSelectedValueChanged Called rating = {rating}");
        await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(rating);
        Debug.WriteLine($"Rating - OnSelectedValueChanged Completed rating = {rating}");
    }


    private string LabelText => (this.Value) switch
    {
        1 => "Very bad",
        2 => "Bad",
        3 => "Sufficient",
        4 => "Good",
        5 => "Awesome!",
        _ => "Rate our product!"
    };
}
```

Comment: First off thank you. Second, to confirm I understand, the re-render is not having a Hover event, it's the Hover event handler changing the text on the page. That text change forces the render - correct? But... why does a render cause the SelectedValueChanged event to fire?

Comment: Before you can click three stars, you hover over it for a split second, so the hover event always precedes the click select.  The double call is an anomaly in the internal code of `MudRating` which I don't have the time or inclination to dissect!

Comment: This is just a good example of why a lot of developers use their own libraries.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis - but could you reproduce the problem first? Because I couldn't.

Comment: @HH - see my second answer to this question which reproduces the problem and explains why.  I guarantee you won't like the MudBlazor code!!  Here's the link https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/blob/ac484251313644594b7ae6efdcb3544101a7f8c1/src/MudBlazor/Components/Rating/MudRating.razor.cs#L105

Comment: @DavidThielen - see my second answer.  I decided I did have the inclination and time so investigated at the MudBlazor code.

Answer (score 1):

After further investigation I can explain what is happening and why.

### Scenario 1

The `MudRating` parameter `SelectedValueChanged` is linked to the component's `OnSelectedValueChanged` method.  This is invoked through the `IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync` with the colateral `ComponentBase` render event.  This method completes and the component renders.  At this point `Value` is 0 and is passed into `MudRating`.

Here comes the smelly bit.  This is the relevant code from `MudRating`:

```cs
[Parameter]
[Category(CategoryTypes.Rating.Data)]
public int SelectedValue
{
    get => _selectedValue;
    set
    {
        if (_selectedValue == value)
            return;

        _selectedValue = value;

        SelectedValueChanged.InvokeAsync(_selectedValue);
    }
}
```

The parameter has the whole set process hanging off it. `_selectedValue` is whatever star we clicked, but `value` is 0. `_selectedValue == value` isn't true so we set `_selectedValue` to 0 and invoke `SelectedValueChanged` with a value of 0!

### Scenario 2

In the second scenario `MudRating` parameter `SelectedValueChanged` is linked directly to the component's `ValueChanged` `EventCallback` parameter.

Here the renderer recognises this direct link and doesn't invoke `ValueChanged` through the `IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync`.  There's no `ComponentBase` automated Rendering, so the `MudRating` isn't re-rendered until the render casued by `SetParametersAsync`.  At this point `Value` has been set to the correct value.

### Scenario 3

Is the same as scenario 1 but with a different `IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync`.

```cs
    Task IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync(EventCallbackWorkItem callback, object? arg)
    {
       return callback.InvokeAsync(arg);
    }
```

There are no automated Render events, so we need to add one to `OnHoveredValueChanged`

```cs
private void OnHoveredValueChanged(int? val)
{
    activeVal = val;
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

Again we have no Render event driven from `OnSelectedValueChanged` to reset Value.

Here's my demo component with debug code and coding for the various scenarios.

```cs
@using System.Diagnostics;
@implements IHandleEvent

<div class="d-flex flex-column align-center">
    <MudRating SelectedValue="Value" SelectedValueChanged="ValueChanged" HoveredValueChanged="OnHoveredValueChanged" />
    <MudText Typo="Typo.subtitle2" Class="deep-purple-text mt-2">@RatingText</MudText>
</div>

@{
    Debug.WriteLine($"Rating - Rendered Value={this.Value}");
}

@code {
    [Parameter] public int Value { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public EventCallback<int> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    private int? activeVal;

    public override Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Rating - SetParameters Called");
        return base.SetParametersAsync(parameters);
    }

    private void OnHoveredValueChanged(int? val)
    {
        activeVal = val;
        //StateHasChanged();
        Debug.WriteLine($"Rating - OnHoveredValueChanged Called rating = {this.Value}");
    }

    private async Task OnSelectedValueChanged(int rating)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Rating - OnSelectedValueChanged Called rating = {rating}");
        await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(rating);
        Debug.WriteLine($"Rating - OnSelectedValueChanged Completed rating = {rating}");
        //StateHasChanged();
    }

    private string RatingText => (activeVal ?? this.Value) switch
    {
        1 => "Very bad",
        2 => "Bad",
        3 => "Sufficient",
        4 => "Good",
        5 => "Awesome!",
        _ => "Rate our product!"
    };

    //override the ComponentBase handler so
    //no automated StateHasChanged calls are made
    //Task IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync(EventCallbackWorkItem callback, object? arg)
    //{
    //    return callback.InvokeAsync(arg);
    //}

    public async Task HandleEventAsync(EventCallbackWorkItem callback, object? arg)
    {
        var task = callback.InvokeAsync(arg);
        if (task.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion && task.Status != TaskStatus.Canceled)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Rating - HandleEventAsync Awaiting rating = {this.Value}");
            StateHasChanged();
            await task;
        }
        StateHasChanged();
        Debug.WriteLine($"Rating - HandleEventAsync Completed rating = {this.Value}");
    }

}
```

Comment: Funny how this comes full circle, main problem with MudRating is that is writes to its own Parameter. (And doesn't await the InvokeAsync).  But I still think a piece is missing, I still can't repro the initial problem with Scenario 1.

Comment: @HH and MrCakaShaunCurtis - **thank you** for putting in the effort to figure this out. It's weird that something so widely used has a commonly hit bug like this. One follow up question, since `SelectedValue` is never supposed to be set (and this really shows why), does that mean that `SelectedValue` is not the present value, but remains the initial value?

Comment: @HH - here's my test Repo for this question - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/SO76891440A

Comment: @HH - it deeper than that in my view: using `ComponentBase` as your base component regardless of the real needs and the context.  See - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5364401/Building-Blazor-Base-Components

Comment: Hmm, the repo does repro it and I can't spot the difference with my code so quickly. I'll have to look into that.